# Jest Your are trying to import a file after the jest environment has been torn down

Tags: import, jestjs

when i import a file into my test file i have the following error :

```
ReferenceError: You are trying to import a file after the Jest environment has been torn down. From __test__/C_Mail.test.js.

      at BufferListStream.Readable (node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:170:22)
      at BufferListStream.Duplex (node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js:60:12)
      at new BufferListStream (node_modules/bl/bl.js:33:16)
      at new IncomingMessageStream (node_modules/tedious/lib/incoming-message-stream.js:34:15)
      at new MessageIO (node_modules/tedious/lib/message-io.js:41:34)
C:\Users\anisb\OneDrive\Bureau\alertemail\projetHexakey\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:174
  var isDuplex = this instanceof Duplex;
                      ^

TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable
    at BufferListStream.Readable (C:\Users\anisb\OneDrive\Bureau\alertemail\projetHexakey\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:174:23)
    at BufferListStream.Duplex (C:\Users\anisb\OneDrive\Bureau\alertemail\projetHexakey\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_duplex.js:60:12)
    at new BufferListStream (C:\Users\anisb\OneDrive\Bureau\alertemail\projetHexakey\node_modules\bl\bl.js:33:16)
    at new IncomingMessageStream (C:\Users\anisb\OneDrive\Bureau\alertemail\projetHexakey\node_modules\tedious\lib\incoming-message-stream.js:34:15)
    at new MessageIO (C:\Users\anisb\OneDrive\Bureau\alertemail\projetHexakey\node_modules\tedious\lib\message-io.js:41:34)
    at C:\Users\anisb\OneDrive\Bureau\alertemail\projetHexakey\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1442:24
    at Socket.onConnect (C:\Users\anisb\OneDrive\Bureau\alertemail\projetHexakey\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:156:7)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1143:10)
```

Can someone help me ?

I tried to solve using jest.UseFakeTimers() but not useful for me, it tried everything on the web but i didn't found the solution

Thanks everybody